# Missing required field Principal - Amazon S3 - Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to resize hosted images in amazon s3 using AWS Lamba. I followed the following tutorial which is given by Amazon.

[Tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/)

however, when I tried to update my bucket policy it always gives an error as **"Missing required field Principal"**

This is my policy code:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yyyy",
      "Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/xxxxx"}     
    }
  ]
}
```

I Couldn't understand why I'm getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have two statements but only the second includes a Principal.

Comment: @jarmod I included Principal to above statement also. then it gives Policy has invalid action error

Comment: See the answer from @Mari. You've accidentally created a hybrid of an S3 bucket policy (which requires Principal) and a regular IAM policy (that does not require, or allow, Principal). For the tutorial in question, your Lambda function needs the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not an S3 bucket policy, but a policy document that grants permissions to your Lambda function to write logs to CloudWatch and put the objects to your S3 bucket.

Please see how to set up that: https://www.screencast.com/t/SjD72va1Zso

Answer (score -3):

Finally, i found good article [Dynamic Resizing of Images for Different Resolutions: AWS Lambda + S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway)

Thank you all

Comment: link seems broken :(